# Is there anybody who knows how to use PJSIP?

Tags: iphone, ios, lync, pjsip

Is there anybody who knows how to use PJSIP in iOS? What is the first step I should take for using it ?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [getting started with PJSIP on iOS webpage](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone)?

Comment: actually, i already read that link since last week. and tried to search at google. But still dont understand how to use it. have you try before?

Comment: The first few steps are 1) download the source code, and 2) open ipjsua.xcodeproj 3) run. Does that work for you?

Comment: actually can't just follow the link. still have a lot to do. The link is not very clear. But thanks. i will mark this as the answer because that link is the first step. :)